# Temporary exhibitions in Helsinki before christmas

Tags: museums, finland, helsinki

We will spend a day in Helsinki in the beginning of December. (As we do most years cruising from Stockholm.) What temporary exhibitions are available in Helsinki's museum or elsewhere at that time?

Comment: You have a few answers but I have to close this thread as "too localized." Please see http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13/localized-questions/24#24. Questions about what happens during {specific time frame} aren't really suitable for this site. Perhaps the question could be reworked if you were looking for more permanent examples of good places to visit, or even something seasonal. But this question will not likely be relevant once this *specific* occasion passes.

Comment: @Robert: Actually, the [answer I posted](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/temporary-exhibitions-in-helsinki-before-christmas/3395#3395) will remain  largely relevant even after December because it lists the major museums and provides links to their exhibition calendars and such. But yeah, maybe the question could be reworded to be more general so that Dec 2011 is just a secondary point?

Comment: If december is too narrow then I would guess that the word "temporary" also should be. Most temporary exhibitions at museums last for a couple of months at the most. Would a rephrasing where "before Christmas" and "beginning of December" make any difference?

Comment: thinking about it - wouldn't it be nice to get a chance to rephrase before being closed?

Comment: Edited it to talk about seasonal museums in Decembers GENERALLY. Voted to reopen edited version. Even as originally posted, the question was quite answerable, if a bit "localized."

Comment: It does seem a bit localized to me but expecting that nobody else is interested in exhibitions in a major city over a two month period seems artificially pessimistic so I personally would stop short of calling it "too localized". When I came across this question I thought it was a good long-tail question even if its details won't still pertain this time next year.

Comment: I agree with @hippietrail. Also, the "Decembers generally" idea doesn't make much sense; it is artificial and changes what the question is asking (there are probably very few to none "seasonal" exhibitions recurring each December!). How about reverting to the original, or alternatively making this an even more general question about Helsinki museums and their temp exhibitions?

Comment: I think the question is absolutely fine even in the original version. Otherwise we would have to close questions concerning for example solar eclipses to because they are very localized.

Comment: Reverted to original form, as per comments (and their upvotes) above. Also cast the 5th vote to reopen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of pointers:

**[Tennispalatsi](http://www.hel.fi/hki/Taimu/en/Home)** (Helsinki Art Museum)

There will be two ongoing exhibitions in December:

- [Akseli Gallen-Kallela - European Master](http://www.hel.fi/wps/portal/Taidemuseo/Artikkeli?WCM_GLOBAL_CONTEXT=/taimu/en/Art%20Museum%20Tennis%20Palace/TP_Nayttely_01)
- [The Power of Colour - Works from the Collections of the State
  Tretyakov Gallery](http://www.hel.fi/wps/portal/Taidemuseo/Artikkeli?WCM_GLOBAL_CONTEXT=/taimu/en/Art%20Museum%20Tennis%20Palace/TP_Nayttely_02)

[image]
<sup>Akseli Gallen-Kallela: Ad astra, 1907</sup>

Tip: free entrace to Tennispalatsi on Fridays :)
<sup>[Or at least used to be - I'm trying to find out if this is still true; will edit later.]</sup>

If you're after something decidedly *Finnish*, you should probably check out the [Gallen-Kallela](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akseli_Gallen-Kallela) one.

**[Kiasma](http://www.kiasma.fi/kiasma_en)** (modern art)

See their [calendar](http://www.kiasma.fi/calendar)

**[Ateneum](http://www.ateneum.fi/default.asp?docId=12532)** (Finnish National Gallery)

They'll have (among others) [these temporary exhibitions](http://www.ateneum.fi/default.asp?docId=12540):

- [The Magic of Lapland](http://www.ateneum.fi/default.asp?docId=12540&showInfo=14383) – Lapland in Art from the 1800s to Today
- [Impressive Stones](http://www.ateneum.fi/default.asp?docId=12540&showInfo=14819) – Two centuries of lithography

...plus [permanent collections](http://www.ateneum.fi/default.asp?docId=12534).

All of the above are in located in the heart of the city. If you're willing to venture out to the suburbs, there's e.g. [**EMMA**](http://www.emma.museum/en/nayttelyt) (Espoo Museum of Modern Art) ~half hour [bus trip](http://www.reittiopas.fi/en/?from_in=rautatieasema&from=&via_in=&via=&via_time=0&to_in=emma) away, with exhibitions like:

- [Contemporary art from China: Yang Fudong - Utopia and Reality](http://www.emma.museum/en/n%C3%A4yttelyt/tulevat/yang-fudong)
- [Red](http://www.emma.museum/en/n%C3%A4yttelyt/punainen)

Of course, there are lots of other places too. For example, you'll find [info on smaller, City of Helsinki owned museums here](http://www.hel.fi/hki/museo/en/Museums+-+Exhibitions). I was actually going to mention, as one example, the same exhibition as Mark did: [Out to Sea – 150 Years of Sailing](http://www.hel.fi/hki/museo/en/Museums+-+Exhibitions/Hakasalmi+Villa) in Helsinki at Hakasalmi Villa, next to Finlandia Hall.

Answer (score 5):

Helsinki City Museum has the 'Out to Sea' exhibit until January, which celebrates 150 years of Sailing in Helsinki:

http://www.hel.fi/hki/Museo/en/museum+news/news+and+events/out+to+sea

> Out to Sea 150 Years of Sailing in Helsinki Hakasalmi Villa,
>
> Mannerheimintie 13d, tel. (09) 3107 8519.
>
> Open 27 May 2011–8 January 2012
> Wed–Sun 11 am – 5 pm, Thu 11 am – 7pm.
>
> FREE ENTRY.